# Whats's wrong with this jquery slider function on ie8?

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, slider

I really don't get it... what I'm doing wrong here?

```
jQuery(function(){
  //vars
  var conveyor = jQuery(".content-conveyor", jQuery("#slideWrapper")),
  item = jQuery(".item", jQuery("#slideWrapper"));

  conveyor.css("width", item.length * parseInt(item.css("width")));

        var sliderOpts = {
    max: (item.length * parseInt(item.css("width"))) - parseInt(jQuery("#slideContent", jQuery("#slideWrapper")).css("width")),
          slide: function(e, ui) { 
            conveyor.css("left", "-" + ui.value + "px");
          }
        };

        jQuery("#slider").slider(sliderOpts);
      });
```

Comment: Could you show the html also?

Comment: that one is what I'm using now.. just change some css, here is the online demo:

http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/377_slider/slider_sourcefiles/slider.html

and here is the official tutorial link:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/making-a-content-slider-with-jquery-ui/

Comment: Using jquery-1.3.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js I get this:

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 12
Char: 12949
Code: 0
URI: jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Using jquery-1.4.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js I get this:

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 116
Char: 165
Code: 0
URI: jquery-1.4.2.min.js

Answer (score 7):

Just for info: jQuery 1.4.3 has solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

invalid argument jquery-1.3.2.min.js

then in all solutions post solutions as

step1)  search return N.toUpperCase()}); in jquery-1.3.2.min.js
step2) add if(K=='Infinitypx'){K=''};if(K=='NaNpx'){K=''}; after searched stmt;

actually this was a bug in jquery-1.3.2.min.js where all the scnerios were not covered.

adding this will sort out that error and it will work smoothly.